# How to view files in binary from bash?

Tags: bash, shell, binary

I would like to view the contents of a file in the current directory, but in binary from the command line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 678, accepted):

[`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) does both binary and hexadecimal.

bin:

```
xxd -b file
```

hex:

```
xxd file
```

Comment: `sudo xxd /dev/diskn | less` is now my new favorite thing.

Comment: ...and it's preinstalled on Mac OS X and on Linux.

Comment: This has the advantage over "hexdump" that it also shows the ASCII form on the side, making it easier to identify the location I want to look at.

Comment: And to dump the output to an ASCII text file for perusing & searching: `xxd file > hex_dump_of_file.txt`

Comment: a supplment: xxd is not only for linux shell. I think it comes with vim. I had vim installed on windows, and I just found I can use xxd in windows too.

Comment: You could even play with binary files in [tag:bash]: [Read a file by bytes in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13890319/1765658)

Answer (score 199):

```
hexdump -C yourfile.bin
```

unless you want to edit it of course. Most linux distros have `hexdump` by default (but obviously not all).

Comment: I like this idea, but like the other suggestions it only outputs hex. Obviously this is much more compact than binary, but I am dealing with very small files so binary is preferred. Is hex the only way I will be able to view the file?

Comment: Well how small is the file? Anything over a couple of bytes and you will start to lose your mind using binary anyway. Hex makes much more sense for most things.  If you are uncomfortable with hex just locate the bytes in which you are interested and convert them using a hex calculator.

Comment: I need to make sure that my file is compressing correctly and I don't know what it should look like in hex (the size of each unit is 7 bits), so I would have to crunch the numbers by hand.

Comment: do you have any methods to see text from binary file? I can get HEX code, but how should i decode it to normal human text?

Comment: What about output of hexdump -C data.bin | hexdump -C

Comment: `hexdump -C` does not show binary output. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 78):

```
vi your_filename
```

hit  <kbd>esc</kbd>

Type `:%!xxd` to view the hex strings, the n `:%!xxd -r` to return to normal      editing.

Comment: I've found `:%!xxd` adding unwanted characters i.e. new line to my file?

Answer (score 40):

As a fallback there's always `od -xc filename`

Answer (score 13):

`sudo apt-get install bless`

Bless is GUI tool which can view, edit, seach and a lot more.
Its very light weight.

Comment: Yes.  I found this to be easier than Vim.

Comment: beware, it comes with mono

Comment: Working in centos using snap: sudo snap install bless-unofficial

Answer (score 13):

If you want to open binary files (in CentOS 7):

```
strings <binary_filename>
```

Comment: IMO this is the simplest most elegant of all the answers. I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Comment: The best answer hands down. This converts the Binary file into a JSON file. Not all heros wear capes,that is true

Comment: It doesn't convert it into JSON file. It only finds the printable strings in an object and show you. It doesn't convert the binary file into text or any format at all.

Answer (score 9):

Hexyl formats nicely: sudo apt install hexyl

[image]

Comment: very nice!/////

Answer (score 6):

```
$ echo -n 'Hello world!' | hd
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64 21              |Hello world!|
0000000c
```

Comment: hd is an alias to "hexdump -C" ... ?

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans Yes indeed. I use it because it is easier to remember.

Comment: And because it is present by default on some systems (Debian).

Answer (score 3):

See [Improved Hex editing in the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_Hex_editing).

Answer (score 3):

To get the output all in a single line in Hexadecimal:

```
xxd -p yourfile.bin | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open emacs (in terminal mode, using `emacs -nw` for instance), and then use Hexl mode: `M-x hexl-mode`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html

Answer (score 1):

to convert a file to its binary codes(hexadecimal representation) we say:

```
xxd filename                                         #
```

e.g:

```
xxd hello.c                                          #
```

to see all the contents and codes in a binary file , we could use commands like `readelf` and `objdump`, `hexdump` ,... .

for example if we want to see all the convert all the contents of a binary file(executable, shared libraries, object files) we say:

```
hexdump binaryfilename
```

e.g.

```
hexdump /bin/bash
```

but readelf is the best utility for analyzing elf(executable and linking format) files. so if we say:

```
readelf -a /bin/bash
```

all the contents in the binary file bash would be shown to us, also we could provide different flags for readelf to see all the sections and headers of an elf file separately, for example if we want to see only the elf header we say:

```
readelf -h /bin/bash
```

for reading all the segments of the file:

```
readelf -l /bin/bash
```

for reading all the sections of the file:

```
readelf -S /bin/sh
```

but again as summary , for reading a normal file like "hello.c" and a binary file like bash in path /bin/bash in linux we say:

```
xxd hello.c

readelf -a /bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use hexdump binary file

```
sudo apt-get install hexdump

hexdump -C yourfile.bin
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765339/12573645