# How can I see the 0s and 1s / machine code from a executable file / object file?

Tags: binary, executable, reverse-engineering, machine-code, object-files

I already tried this, I opened a a.out file with a text editor but I get only a bunch of characters with some instructions in it like:

üÙ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing File in Binary in Terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765311/viewing-file-in-binary-in-terminal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`hexdump`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm). Something like:

```
$ hexdump -X a.out
```

It will give you just that: an hexadecimal dump of the file.

Having said that, another possibility might include using [GDB's disassemble command](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_50.html).

Answer (score 3):

Lookup your local friendly [Hex Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor).

Answer (score 0):

To see the disassembly (with opcode bytes) of the code only, not including any file headers:

```
objdump -d a.aot
```

Answer (score 0):

Executable files come in several formats. For Unix/Linux it's ELF:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

For Windows it's PE:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Use the objdump tools to see the opcodes as others have pointed out

Answer (score 0):

when you open a binary file you would see unreadable characters, the reason is that ascii encoding uses 7 bits , therefore all the characters that have a code point from 128 to 255 won't be recognized by the editor and therefore you see unknown characters.

if you want to see all the contents of a binary file , you could use programs like hexdump,objdump and readelf, for example lets say we want to dissect /bin/bash as a binary file in linux(elf) into its bytes in hexadecimal representation, so we say:

hexdump /bin/bash

but the best tool for these kind of files is: readelf

if we want to see all the contents of a binary file in a more human-readable format than the hexdump output we could just say:

readelf -a /bin/bash

and we would see all different sections of the binary file (elf header, program header , sections header and data).

also using other flags we could see only one header at a time, or we could just disassemble the .text sections in the file and so on.