# How can I open inside shell commands, binaries, and analyze their code?

Tags: macos, shell

Just out of curiosity I would like to examine what is inside these commands. Like `mkdir` or `adb` command or other things inside `/bin` or `/sbin` folder. I know they are binaries so, i searched some answers like below. I found `xxd -b <filename>` or `strings . But i want more clearer view, is it possible. And is there a way we can know in which language they are written? For example for mac commands, what language they are written?

[How to view files in binary from bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765311/how-to-view-files-in-binary-from-bash)

Comment: For some parts of macOS (including a lot of command-line utilities), the source code is available at https://opensource.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

Practical answer: most binaries are written in 'C', some are written in 'C++'. See below on logic to tell which one. Note that I'm not macos expert - I believe Linux tools will work the same for `macos`

Most of the files in /bin and /usr/bin are `stripped binaries` (the minority are symbolic links which create "aliases", or small scripts that implement existing commands, usually using other binaries).

The fact the the binary is `stripped` means that a debugger (gdb, or other tools like ltrace, etc.) to see function names, variable names, etc. (do `man strip` to see what is removed). One of the items that can **NOT** be 'stripped' is the list of shared libraries.

Given this information, possible to get some clues from the list of shared libraries. C++ programs will usually link with the 'standard C++' shared library (libstdc++.so.N, where N is the version, currently at 6). Most other languages have their own run-time shared library that will be linked. Most 'C' programs will link with the standard C runtime (/lib.c.so.N).

Bottom line: consider the following process:

- Do `file -L /bin/sh` (or any other binary):
- If output contain 'script' in the output, the program is implemetned a s script
- If output indicates a binary (`ELF shared object`, or similar):
- Run 'ldd /bin/sh`
- If output contain 'libstdc++.so' - code contain SOME c++ - most like C++ source
- If output contain 'libc.so.' - program contain SOME c - most like C program

```
owner@vm1:~/Projects/SO/ff1$ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=452da38d6212b692cd80eb0dd1c99cf853da31ae, stripped
owner@vm1:~/Projects/SO/ff1$ ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcb87fe000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f5e7cd8e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5e7cb8a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5e7c799000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5e7d2d2000)



wner@vm1:~/Projects/SO/ff1$ file /usr/bin/zlib-flate 
/usr/bin/zlib-flate: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=bbc1bc3fbbb71c7ae3cf9ef9f2876098df3fd752, stripped
owner@vm1:~/Projects/SO/ff1$ ldd !$
ldd /usr/bin/zlib-flate
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffeb3be000)
    libqpdf.so.21 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqpdf.so.21 (0x00007f2f8ee45000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2f8eabc000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2f8e8a4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f8e4b3000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f2f8e24b000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2f8e02e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2f8dc90000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f8f313000)
```

Note:
* Technically, possible to "trick" this logic with static linking, but most (all) binaries will use dynamic linking.

Comment: The analogue of `ldd` on macOS is `otool -L`; the main system library is `usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`.